# Multicontainer Docker application failing on deploy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have a problem with deploying my application to elastic beanstalk at Amazon. My application is a multi-container Docker application that includes node server and mongoDB inside of it. Somehow the application crashes every time and I get this bizarre error from mongoDB.
Error is as follows:

```
18-05-28T12:53:02.510+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 3867 processes, 32864 files. Number of processes should be at least 16432 : 0.5 times number of files.
2018-05-28T12:53:02.540+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-05-28T12:53:02.541+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-05-28T12:53:03.045+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2018-05-28T12:53:03.045+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-05-28T12:53:03.045+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-05-28T12:53:03.045+0000 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2018-05-28T12:53:03.047+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2018-05-28T12:53:03.161+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-05-28T12:53:03.161+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2018-05-28T12:53:03.161+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
```

This is my Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes":[
    {
      "name": "mongo-app",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/mongo-app"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "some-api",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/some-api"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "mongo-app",
        "image": "mongo:latest",
        "memory": 128,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 27017,
            "containerPort": 27017
          }
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
          {
            "sourceVolume": "mongo-app",
            "containerPath": "/data/db"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "server",
        "image": "node:8.11",
        "memory": 128,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 80,
            "containerPort": 8001
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          "mongo-app"
        ],
        "mountPoints":[
          {
            "sourceVolume": "some-api",
            "containerPath": "/some-data"
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.11
RUN mkdir -p /api
WORKDIR /api
COPY package.json /api
RUN cd /api && npm install
COPY . /api
EXPOSE 8001
CMD ["node", "api/app.js"]
```

Any Ideas why the application is crashing and does not deploy? It seems to me that the mongoDB is causing the problem but I cant understand or find the root of the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to figure this out as well.

The solution: Add a mountpoint for `"containerPath": "/data/configdb"`. Mongo expects to be able to write to both `/data/db` and `/data/configdb`.

Also, you might want to bump up `"memory": 128` for Mongo to something higher.